# How to delete the current line when looping through a file in bash?

Tags: bash

I want to write a bash script that loops through a text file, takes a line, does stuff with it, and then removes that line from the input file.

Right now I can loop through and do stuff with the line. But how do I delete it afterwards?
At the moment I have:

```
while read p; do
   echo "$p"
done < test.txt
```

Now what? Thanks :)

Comment: Sounds like a use case for `sed` to me.

Comment: I suggest always deleting the first line.

Comment: Why do you want to delete it line by line? Isn't enough to process all the lines and remove the file (or just truncate it) at the end?

Comment: As @axiac noted, if you delete all lines at the end you will have an empty file. So, simply process it and when done delete it or overwrite it with `/dev/null` (`cat /dev/null > test.txt`).

Comment: @axiac, because I want to continue at that point in case I need to restart the script, but don't want to do the stuff for each line again that I already used. So I thought deleting the line in place would be the best option.

Answer (score 0):

You can do (remove `x` character in each lines):

```
{
    while read p; do
       tr -d x <<< "$p"
    done < test.txt
} | sponge test.txt
```

to modify *in place*.

`sponge` utility from `moreutils`.